# How to write a shell script to find PID and Kill

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a script that looks for the PID of another script that ran previously.  Once it finds that PID it then sends a kill signal.

I can find the PID but the kill signal does not process, I get a return message that it is not a PID.

Here is what I am doing:

```
#!/bin/bash   
 PID=`ps -eaf | grep "start.sh" | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "$PID"    
    if [[ -z "$PID" ]];
     then(
            echo "Start script is not running!"
    )else(
            kill -9 $PID
    )fi
```

The script it is trying to kill starts many other scripts so I am hoping that killing `start.sh` will kill all child processes.

Comment: Have you considered instead using the `killall` command to kill a process by name instead of by PID?

Comment: Are you aware of [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)?

Comment: I have tried "killall start.sh" which returns "no process found".  That is why I am trying to kill the PID.

Comment: Shell scripts don't use `(` and `)` to delimit blocks like that. Remove them. Also avoid ALL_CAPS variables. They are generally reserved for the shell/system to use (also generally for exported variables).

Comment: I have tried pkill as well, but this the not process it.  When I run top it still shows as running.

Comment: @MPNation: btw, don't mistake `killall` with `killall5`.

Comment: @MPNation, assuming that the actual target command's argv is something like `sh start.sh` or `bash start.sh`, indeed, pkill won't find it out-of-the-box -- but `pkill -f start.sh`, by contrast, _will_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
ps -eaf | grep "start.sh" | awk '{print $2}'
```

you create a subshell with the word `start.sh` in it. `grep` will then pick up on its own process and the `start.sh` one so you will get two PIDs back.

This means when you are trying to kill both  `start.sh` and the

```
ps -eaf | grep "start.sh" | awk '{print $2}'
```

processes. The `start.sh` will die but the other will no longer exist so can't be killed, so it gives you an error.

If you were to split up the commands you might have better luck:

```
PIDS=$(ps -eaf)
PID=$(echo "$PIDS" | grep "start.sh" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: A more common way to do this is with a grep pattern that doesn't match itself; for instance, `[s]tart[.]sh` matches `start.sh` but not itself; that way you don't need to bother with buffering output in a shell variable.

Comment: ...that said, by far the better practice would be to figure out why pkill isn't working for the OP and fix that. :)

Comment: I still think that `[s]tart[.]sh` would match both processes but pkill isn't/wasn't working because one of the process that it captured the PID of  to kill had ended so when it tried to kill it, it wasn't there so it errored.

Comment: Ahh. One can always use `pgrep` and do the kill itself if one wants to. And no, `[s]tart[.]sh` won't match both, because `[s]` only matches `s`; it doesn't match the literal string `[s]`.

Comment: Ah yeah, just though it through. That's smart :P And yeah pgrep is an option, I did it my way because it was closest to OP original question and it helps them understand why it happened more...I hope :D

Comment: That is a rather convoluted way of doing it. `grep start.sh < <(ps -eaf) | grep -v grep` saves spawning an additional subshell and uses **redirection** instead of piping the output of `echo`

Comment: When your script will be maintained by others, also add a comment. I am afraid of a noob who thinks he can improve the code by merging the two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pgrep`:

```
PID=$(pgrep yourprocesname)
```

Comment: `pgrep <yourprocessname> | xargs -i{} kill -9 {}`

Comment: If you have `pgrep`, you should also have `pkill`, and should use it directly.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pidof` rather then `ps -ef`

```
PID=`pidof start.sh | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "$PID csshst will be stopped"
if [[ -z "$PID" ]]; then
(
        kill -9 $PID
)
fi
```

Comment: When answering it's important to explain how it works and why it should be the selected answer. We want to educate, not just toss out code, so the person knows how to fix the problem if it occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that may be useful for someone:

```
#!/bin/bash  
kill-process-by-name(){  
   processes=$(ps -A)
   kill -9 `echo "$processes" | grep "$1" | cut -f2 -d" "`
}

kill-process-by-name "start.sh"
```

Comment: What good is a script that defines a function but never calls it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added a call to the function.  The idea was that you would put that at the top of your script and call it as needed.  This way you won't have duplicate code if your script decides to kill more than one process.

Comment: There's also no protection here against finding and killing the `grep start.sh` process, as opposed to the `start.sh` process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a really good point.  I've made sure that the ps command is evaluated before the grep command takes place.

Comment: Needs more quoting; right now `echo $processes` collapses everything into one line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I had originally tested it in zsh where it had worked without the quotes.  Quotes have been added so that it functions properly under bash.

Comment: Not just a bash thing, a POSIX sh thing; zsh violates the standard by not performing string splitting on unquoted expansion.

Comment: (To cite my sources on that -- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05; "After parameter expansion [...] the shell shall scan the results of expansions and substitutions that did not occur in double-quotes for field splitting")

Comment: When answering it's important to explain how it works and why it should be the selected answer. We want to educate, not just toss out code, so the person knows how to fix the problem if it occurs again.

Answer (score -1):

```
trashPID=`pidof start.sh | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "$PID csshst will be stopped"
if [[ -z "$PID" ]]; then
(
        kill -9 $PID
)
fi
```

purely

Comment: When answering it's important to explain how it works and why it should be the selected answer. We want to educate, not just toss out code, so the person knows how to fix the problem if it occurs again.